# CoreBluetooth - not discovering services

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-bluetooth

I'm experiencing an interesting issue with CoreBluetooth. I'm using an iPhone 6 Plus and an iPhone 4S for my test. Both devices are on 8.2

I have the following setup in my class's init method:

```
 _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self  
                                                        queue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
                                                      options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]}];

 _peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                               queue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
                                                             options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]}]; 

//My characteristic and service setup is here and I finally add them to the peripheral: 
[_peripheralManager addService:transferService];
[_peripheralManager addService:anotherService];
```

I then start the peripheral manager advertisment and central scan as follows:

```
[self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:@{CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey : @"My name",
                                           CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:my_UUID]] }];

[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:SAME_UUID_AS_ABOVE]]
                                              options:nil];
```

At this poin the delegate method:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

is called, the advertisment data dictionary is consistent with the setup I've performed in the init method, however by the time I get to didDiscoverServices I can't see any services for the peripheral. I've checked in the console, the pointer is the same (I store the peripheral in a property) and so is the UUID. An interesting point is that when I first discover the peripheral, the name is correct, e.g.

```
<CBPeripheral: 0x1700f8500, identifier = xxxxx, name = My Name, state = disconnected>
```

but then by the time it gets to didDiscoverServices - `<CBPeripheral: 0x1700f8500, identifier =xxxx, name = iPhone, state = connected>`

Note the difference in the name.

I tried setting the peripheral and central to different queues with no result. My question is, is it possible to use a peripheral and central at the same time and could that cause a problem when discovering services?

**EDIT:** Another oddity. 
1. If I restart both devices, then add a `sleep` call on the 6 Plus between the calls to advertising and scanning I can see the service from the 4S. 
2. If I remove the `sleep` and run the app again, I can still see the service. However, when I plug the 4S to Xcode and try to drive the flow from there - I can't seem to get it. Subsequent attempts from the 4S fail as well.

Comment: When you say that no services are visible, have you called `discoverServices` on your discovered peripheral?

Comment: Yes, I have the, I get the didDiscoverServices delegate call, as I mentioned in my problem description I checked the peripheral is the same as the one I connected to. The services array is empty.

Comment: Sorry,  I see that now.  What do you pass to `discoverServices`?  `nil`? Also, is `my_UUID` one of the services you have added to the peripheral (i.e.. *transferService* or *anotherService*) ?

Comment: Hi, I do the following: `[self.discoveredPeripheral discoverServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:my_UUID]]];` the UUID I'm using is the one for the transferService

Comment: Are you waiting for the callback that indicates that bluetooth is powered on before advertising/scanning?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yup, I even went one step beyond and moved the call to start scanning to the 'peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising' method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was adding the services to the peripheral manager before immediately after its init, i.e. didn't way for the state completion block.

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue related to adding the service before the peripheral was fully inited.  I found that adding the service in the peripheralManagerDidUpdateState: delegate method was a good place to add the service since this is called right after the peripheral is inited.

Answer (score 0):

You should check:

```
(void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral { 
    if (self.manager.state >= CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn) { 
        [self.manager addService:self.service]; 
    }
    else {
        [self.manager removeService:self.service];
    }
}
```

This will ensure you add the service when BLE is turned on and remove the service when it's turned off.